# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/black_title')

Tags: java, android

I am having issues trying to resolve the specified error.

Here's my xml code for `activity_craft_your_story.xml` layout:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/titleGraphic"
android:src="@drawable/black_title" />
```

This is the code that I am currently trying to link that file with `CraftYourStoryActivity.java`:

```
public void BitmapDrawable (Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, Object BitmapDrawable) 
{       
    ImageView titleGraphic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    titleGraphic.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_title);    
}
```

I don't know if that's the right one to use but I need a working title graphic. What can I do?

Comment: do you have a drawable called black_title? Do you have any compile time error in your resources ?

Comment: I do have that.  It's in my drawable folder, along with the other drawable folders.  Every time I think that I have it fixed, it does the same error.  It's quite bothersome.

Comment: @Hatter what did you do to fix the problem? it would be helpful to write the answer to your own question then accept it. PS it takes two days before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the drawable folder.
Make sure it contains the black_title.png image and it's name is correct.

android:src="@drawable/black_title" gives you error until it doesn't got the /res/drawable/black_title.png

Comment: I have the drawable, and it is showing fine in the design view of my layout. Yet, I still get the error! What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the drawable resource called "black_title" in your drawable folder ?

Incase If you want to keep one resource for all different resolutions then create the folder /res/drawable and place black_title.png in it. Build the project. Now this resource will be taken.

Comment: I did all that.  then when I restarted the workspace (something wonky happened), I am back to the same error message.

Comment: Try to do a clean build. If possible, post the res folder screenshot from eclipse. Also what is the purpose of the function BitmapDrawable ?

Comment: Cool.  Happy that it was helpful.

Comment: I have the drawable, and it is showing fine in the design view of my layout. Yet, I still get the error! What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning , building or syncing IDE with files .